# Return the only non-FALSE value in an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following array: {FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;"$D$3";FALSE}. There is only one non-FALSE value. Is there a formula that I can use on this array to return this value (here "$D$3")?

I tried max, min, sum, but since it is not a number value, it does not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LOOKUP` function:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/({FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;"$D$3";FALSE}<>FALSE),{FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;"$D$3";FALSE})
```

- `(array<>FALSE)` returns an array of `{TRUE;FALSE...}` depending on condition
- `1/(…)` will then convert that to an array of `{1;DIV/0;...}`
- `LOOKUP(2,1/(…),orig_array)` will then return the last position in the original array that was not false.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your array is in a *column*, use something like:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*",A1:A5,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the one non-FALSE entry is text, not numeric:

`=LOOKUP(REPT("z",255),Rng)`

Replace Rng with the desired array.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop:

```
Sub dural()
    arr = Array(False, False, False, "$D$3", False)
    For Each a In arr
        If a <> False Then
            MsgBox a
        End If
    Next a
End Sub
```

[image]